# Finding equations of all lines that lie entirely on a surface and passes through a point

Tags: multivariable-calculus, surfaces

Let $S$ be the surface $x^2 + y^2 - z^2 = 1$ and $P(1,1,-1)$ be a point on $S$. Find the equations for all lines passing through the point P which lie entirely on the surface $S$.

At point $P$, the equation of the tangent plane of the surface $S$ is: $x + y + z =1$ (1)

The line equation $L: r = <1 + at, 1 + bt, -1+ct>$ must satisfy both equation (1) and the equation of the surface.

Substituting $L$ into the tangent plane equation yields $(a + b + c)t = 0$

While subsittuting $L$ into the surface equation yields $2(a + b -c) + (a^2 + b^2 -c^2)t = 0$

We must have $a + b +c =0 , a + b -c = 0, a^2 + b^2 -c^2 = 0$, which then solving yields $a = b = c = 0$.

I might have done something wrong while working on this question, thanks @Arthur for the help and information for me to improve my question.

Any help on this will be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: The lines will be perpendicular to the surface normal at $P$. That means they must lie in the tangent plane at $P$.

**Analyzing your attempt:**

You have the right plane. And you are right that the plane gives you the equation
$$
a+b+c = 0
$$
when you insert the expression for the line into the equation for the plane. However, you didn't insert correctly into the equation for the surface. There we have
$$
(at+1)^2+(bt+1)^2 - (ct-1)^2 = 1\\
t^2(a^2+b^2-c^2) + 2t(a+b+c) = 0
$$
which simplifies to $a^2+b^2 = c^2$. Now you have two equations you can solve which should give you your two lines.

**Alternate solution:** This is how I first thought to solve the problem: Rearrange the plane equation to $z = 1-x-y$, and insert that into the equation for the surface:
$$
x^2+y^2-(1-x-y)^2 = 1\\
x^2 + y^2 - (1+x^2+y^2-2x-2y+2xy) = 1\\
xy-x-y+1 =0\\
(x-1)(y-1) = 0
$$
What does this mean? When we inserted the equation for the plane into the equation for the surface, we got a third equation which represents a different set of points in space. This third set intersects the plane in the same places that the surface does, and the new equation is easily solved to give $x = 1$ or $y = 1$. From here it's not difficult to find the two lines in the plane $x+y+z = 1$ satisfying either of these constraits, and we're done.

Comment: @Arthur I do know how to find the tangent plane at point P, but I cannot visualise it geometrically on how this works. I was thinking that the lines contained in the tangent plane will only pass through the point P and possibly not lie in the surface. Could you explain this further please?

Comment: @Derp At this stage we don't technically know for certain that there are any lines that lie in the surface (remember that "there are no such lines" is an allowed answer, although it's incorrect in this specific instance). But if they _do_ exist (I happen to know that they do), then they must be perpendicular to the surface normal, and a line which is perpendicular to the surface normal _must_ lie in the tangent plane. Now what remains is to check whether there are any lines which are both in the tangent plane and in the surface, and if there are, find their equations.

Comment: @Derp For a visual aid, take a look at [this wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ruled_surface). The first image, with the strings, shows exactly your surface (or possibly some stretched variation) with lots of straight lines in it and two lines intersecting at each point.

Comment: @Arthur, I am not sure about this, I did the following:

I found the equation of the tangent plane which is: $x + y + z = 1$
I also have the line equation: $<1, 1, -1> + <a, b, c>t = <x, y, z>$
Substituting both inside yields me with $(a + b + c)t = 0$ and hence $a + b + c =0$

I then substituted the line equaition into the surface equation, giving me $2(a + b + c) + (a^2 + b^2 + c^2)t = 0$ which implies that $a + b + c = 0$ and $a^2 + b^2 + c^2 = 0$

All the equations here has led me to $a = b = c = 0$, am I doing something wrong?

Sorry for the messy comment, appreciate your help!

Comment: @Derp You did some sign mistakes. I added details to my answer.

Comment: @Arthur Many thanks for correcting my mistakes, using those 2 equations, I obtained $ab=0$, so I I must have 2 cases:

1. $a = 0, b \neq 0$ and so $c = -b$
This yields me the line equation: $<1, 1 + bt, -1-bt>$

2. $a \neq 0, b = 0$ and so $c = -a$
This yields me the line equation $<1 + at, 1, -1-at>$

Do I need to find out what the 2 unknowns are in the equation? Because it seems like I only have 2 equations, which mean 1 unknown is arbitrary.

Comment: @Derp It seems that way initially. However, it turns out that it doesn't matter what you set the final unknown to (as long as it isn't $0$), because the only thing that changes is the speed at which you move along the line as you vary $t$. It's still the same line.

Comment: @Arthur, thank you I got it, the two lines are simply the ones I mentioned above, letting $at$ and $bt$ as arbitrary values. I substituted the 2 lines into both the surface and the tangent plane equation and both yielded me with the correct answers!

Really thank you for helping me out on this question!

Comment: @Derp No problem. Small technicality: It is not $at$ and $bt$ you set to arbitrary values, but $a$ and $b$. Also, kudos to you for inserting and checking that your lines actually lie where they're supposed to. Strictly speaking you never needed to insert and check that they lie in the tangent plane, since the problem only cared about the surface; the tangent plane and the fact that the lines lie in it was something you constructed to help you find the relevant equations. Checking that the lines actually go through $P$ is more important.